# How to specify path of python file in apache

Tags: python, apache, path

I am building a server on windows10 now.
The server to use is apache and the language is python.
Modified apache's httpd.conf to use python files.
I created a python file called helloworld.py under htdocs.
The contents of the file are as follows.

```
#!C:\Users\z05974ac\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
# coding:utf-8
print ("Content-Type: text/html\n");
print ("Hello World!");
```

The first line is entering the result of where python.
However, the following error message was displayed.

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

I think there is a problem with the way the path is set.
But I don't understand the cause.
I would appreciate your teaching.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you have `mod_python` installed and activated in config?

Comment: The code has been modified as follows.
print ("Content-Type: text/html\n")
print ("Hello World!")

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much on Apache, but is it because you have a semi-colon at the end of your lines? Python just requires a new line to separate code, all C languages need a semi-colon at the end of them. Just rewrite the lines as:

```
print ("Content-Type: text/html\n")
print ("Hello World!")
```

Comment: You can put semicolons at the end of lines in Python without problems. The error here is most likely due to the python interpretor either not being in the path or not associated with .py files

Comment: Thank you for answering.
It was a rudimentary mistake
Immediately, I tried to correct the point you pointed out.
But it didn't work.
There was no change in the corrected error message